# MySQL: Two different results for the same query

Tags: mysql, difference

I'm confused because a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `categories`.`name` 
FROM  `categories` 
INNER JOIN  `expenses` ON  `expenses`.`cat` 
WHERE `categories`.`name` LIKE 't%'
ORDER BY  `expenses`.`updated_at` DESC
```

gives two different results alternately.

What is a possible reason for that? Both tables has primary keys and there is a relationship (one-to-many) between them.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: I dont know mysql source code but I only guess there are multiple record with same `updated_at` value? And mysql can pick them "randomly" based on many factors

Comment: Your guess is right, but there is a row with `updated_at` that has latest timestamp than the rest so I suppose it should be always first.

Comment: expenses.cat is always true

Comment: @Strawberry that was a real eye-opener. Thank you! (:

Answer (score 2):

here is your problem

INNER JOIN  `expenses` ON  `expenses`.`cat`

it is malformed

edit:
it should be of the form (please ignore table names and columns)

```
from user u
join comment c on c.sender=u.id and TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, c.theDate, now())<169
where u.reportsTo=2
```

Comment: so frankly i wouldnt know what to expect from what the question's sql  posed as it looks a bit off

Comment: if i were to read @strawberry 's comment in the face of bad data coming back (and thinking your sql in question is getting back bizarre data), i would substitute `true` into your sql from question, and again have no clue what data to expect

Answer (score 2):

I think you should get the proper result by the following, derived from yours, query:

```
SELECT 
    `categories`.`name`, 
    MAX(`expenses`.`updated_at`) AS `max_for_group_updated_at`
FROM  
    `categories` 
    INNER JOIN  `expenses` ON  `expenses`.`cat` = `categories`.`name`  -- //or other proper join condition
WHERE 
    `categories`.`name` LIKE 't%'
GROUP BY 
    `categories`.`name`
ORDER BY  
    `max_for_group_updated_at` DESC
```

Comment: I'm really glad it helped then :)